# how to execute a batch file on a remote machine using MSBuild?

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have a service running in a remote machine and have written two batch files to stop and start the service respectively. I have a MSBuild file that should call the batch file to stop the service, copy all the dlls to the remote machine and then start the service back using the other batch file. I am able to copy all my binaries to the machine but somehow not able to call the batch files and execute them. Tried various things including

```
    Target Name="StopService">
    <Exec Command="\\BLRWVENVOY01\JenkinsFolder\BatchFile\KillService.bat" />
    <Exec Command="echo it is a test!" />
    </Target>
```

I wrote this code inside my MSBuild file. The folder has sharing enabled. What is it that I am doing wrong or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-use-build-events-in-msbuild-projects?view=vs-2019.  I believe you want something like:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
        <Command>Cmd.exe /c "\\BLRWVENVOY01\JenkinsFolder\BatchFile\KillService.bat"</Command>
        <Message>Running KillService.bat</Message>
    </PreBuildEvent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```